# how to display a list of report-bots that are available to me

Tags: pyrogram

I used to use "iter_dialogs" to get a list of available chats. But this method has stopped working. Can you suggest an alternative? And is it possible to get a list of report-bots to write to them later? I will be very glad of any help.

Answer (score 0):

`iter_dialogs()` doesn't work anymore, as it has been replaced by `get_dialogs()`. See Pyrogram's [Release Notes for v2](https://docs.pyrogram.org/releases/v2.0):

> **Iter_* methods have been removed:** This means there is now only one way of iterating through items by using the respective get_* methods which are all turned into generators. Some of the methods have been renamed as well:
>
> - `iter_history` becomes `get_chat_history()`.
> - `iter_chat_members` becomes `get_chat_members()`.
> - `iter_dialogs` becomes `get_dialogs()`.
> - `iter_profile_photos` becomes `get_chat_photos()`.

---

As for your second question about report bots, I have no idea what you're talking about there. You might want to edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: I was able to find a solution, thanks a lot